# Bulk Copy or Update data from one database to another

Tags: c#, .net, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, bulkupdate

I would like to bulk copy or update data from one Database to another by making use of the following criteria:

- Copy the data row if it doesn't already exist based on the barcode column
- Update the current data row in the destination database if the barcode column data already exists

This is my code where I get the data from the local database and BulkCopy it to the central database. How do I add those conditions in my code?

```
string localConnectionString = GetLocalConnection();
string sqlConnectionStringNP01 = GetNP01Connection();

using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(localConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        // Getting Local DB Data
        cmd.CommandType = commandType;
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240;
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        adapter.Dispose();
    }

    // Copying to Central Database
    using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionStringNP01))
    {
        conn2.Open();

        using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn2))
        {
            // I want to add the code to do the checking here if possible
            copy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
            copy.BatchSize = 1000;
            copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;
            copy.WriteToServer(dt);
            copy.NotifyAfter = 1000;

            MessageBox.Show("Data successfully transfered to Central Database", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` can insert, and insert only. If you need conditional updates, you'll have to import the data to a staging table, then run any updates/merges/deletes what have you afterwards, using that table as the input. If you have very many updates this way, using `SqlBulkCopy` may not be cost effective, and you're better off processing individual rows, or at least splitting the batches in rows to change/rows to insert first (using transactions). If you need to do this continuously, or on a schedule, consider using transactional or merge replication instead of rolling your own code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So if I split the data into the total rows that needs to be updated and total rows that need to be inserted, then I can use the SqlBulkCopy for the insert data and the another method to update the other data?

Comment: Yes, that's one way. If there's any chance of the data getting modified inbetween, though, you have to take some care to ensure the result is transactionally correct. This can get complicated if you're doing it outside the database; bulk copying all the data first and then running a stored procedure that does the update/insert in a single transaction is easier.

Comment: Is one database accessible from the other? If yes, why not do it with a simple stored procedure?

Comment: You can use a toll such as [SqlBulkTools](https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools) it supports BulkInsertOrUpdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jeroen wrote in his comment, `SqlBulkCopy` can only insert.

However, you could insert in a temporary table and create a SQL to perform your `MERGE` statement in your destination table.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/)

This library is not free but offers the `BulkMerge` option you are looking for.

```
using (BulkOperation copy = new BulkOperation(conn2))
{
    copy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
    copy.BatchSize = 1000;
    copy.BatchTimeout = 240;
    copy.BulkMerge(dt);

    MessageBox.Show("Data successfully transfered to Central Database", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're using a specific connection class to Sql Server, so your code doesn't need to work with other RDBMS. 
I suggest you to use a stored procedure to add all your conditions encapsulated in a transaction:

```
DECLARE
        @CrLf nvarchar(2),
        @Exception nvarchar(4000)

SET @CrLf=char(13) + char(10)

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN YOUR_TRAN

    --YOUR CODE

    COMMIT TRAN YOUR_TRAN
END TRY    
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN YOUR_TRAN

        SELECT
            @Exception='Error number: ' + CAST(COALESCE(ERROR_NUMBER(), 0) as nvarchar) + @CrLf + 
            'Procedure name: ' + COALESCE(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 'N\A') + @CrLf + 
            'Error row: ' + CAST(COALESCE(ERROR_LINE(), 0) as nvarchar) + @CrLf +
            'Error message: ' + COALESCE(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'N\A')

        PRINT(@Exception)
        RAISERROR (@Exception, -- Message text.
                    16, -- Severity.
                    1 -- State.
                    );
END CATCH
```